# signed_request is null on IPad Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I've developed an app for Facebook Fanpage. It's working pretty well. When I view my Facebook fanpage app by web browser, I can get the signed_request parameter in my POST method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/facebook/competition**", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView facebookPost(HttpServletRequest request)
throws SAXException,IOException,
ParserConfigurationException {

logger.info("FACEBOOK SIGNED REQUEST POST: " +  
request.getParameter("signed_request"));
```

But when I view my fanpage app by Facebook app for IPAD, looks like the request goes into the GET method and signed_request value is null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/facebook/competition**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView facebookGet(HttpServletRequest request)
throws SAXException,IOException,
ParserConfigurationException {

logger.info("FACEBOOK SIGNED REQUEST GET: " +  
request.getParameter("signed_request"));
```

Do you know why this doesn't go into my POST method?

Many thanks,

Comment: _“Do you know why this doesn't go into my POST method?”_ – presumably because it is __not__ a POST request …?

Comment: But Facebook makes sure that they will call the POST method.